# Rearrange data from one column into multiple rows

Tags: excel, text

I have a text file that is one very long column that looks like this:

```
Title_1
Data_1
Data_2
Data_3
Title_2
Data_1
Data_2
Data_3
Data_4
Data_5
Title_3
Data_1
Title_4
Title_5
Data_1
Data_2
```

I would like to rearrange these data into rows and columns:

```
Title_1     Data_1     Data_2     Data_3      
Title_2     Data_1     Data_2     Data_3     Data_4     Data_5 
Title_3     Data_1     
Title_4     
Title_5     Data_1     Data_2
```

Note that `'title'` always begins with 'N' followed by other letters/numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TitlesAndData()

    Dim lrows As Long
    Dim counterRow As Long, counterCol As Long

    lrows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    counterRow = 0
    counterCol = 3

    For i = 1 To lrows
        If Left(Cells(i, 1), 1) = "N" Then
            counterRow = counterRow + 1
            counterCol = 3
            Cells(counterRow, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Else
            counterCol = counterCol + 1
            Cells(counterRow, counterCol).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! How do I run this, is it just a macro in excel? Thanks again!

Comment: @user2861089 - it's just a macro in Excel.  https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/